# Return multiple variables from single method with different data types in java

Tags: java, spring

I am new at java . I  have method witch contain some variables with different data type  i.e. String and Array

```
            pNumber=rs.getString("pNumber");
            userName=rs.getString("userName");
            simOperater=rs.getString("simOperater");
            AdharNumber=rs.getString("AdharNumber");
            rechargeAmount[i]=rs.getString("rechargeAmount");
            activeDate[i]=rs.getString("activeDate");
            plainDeatils[i]=rs.getString("plainDeatils");
```

and I want to return all the variables from single method in java so what approach should I use please help

Comment: Sadly, Java doesn't allow multiple return values. So, if you want to return multiple values of the same type, you could use an Array for example. Otherwise, you could always create a Wrapper-class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to write more lines, you can also set the return type of your method to **Object** and return your variable as you normally would, but then cast the returned object into the right type as it was before.

e.g.

```
class test {
    static Object test_return(int which) {
        String s = "This is a string";
        int i = 100;

        if(which == 0) {
            return s;
        } else {
            return i;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String s = (String) test_return(0);
        int i = (int) test_return(1);
                
        System.out.println("String: " + s + "\nint: " + i);
    }
}
```

output:

```
String: This is a string
int: 100
```

*edit:*
since you are new to java, you might not understand how types exactly work here. so I would suggest you read [this](https://beginnersbook.com/2014/09/java-autoboxing-and-unboxing-with-examples/) and [this](https://www.programiz.com/java-programming/autoboxing-unboxing) to learn more about **autoboxing** and **unboxing**

Answer (score 4):

just return a response object

```
public class MyResponse {
public String pNumber;
public String userName;
//....
}
```

usage:

```
public MyResponse yourMethod() {
MyResponse myResponse = new MyResponse();
myResponse.pNumber=rs.getString("pNumber");
myResponse.userName=rs.getString("userName");
//...
return myResponse;
}
```

Comment: From the names and the code the OP showed us, I guess the results together represent some entity from the real world. So, you might add a remark that the OP should probably use a better class name than `MyResponse`.